# How to ckeck many linked properties in angular2 and d3?

Tags: d3.js, typescript, angular

I am trying to make linked views using d3 and angular2. Currently, I have one property linked, the selected item, which is updated for all views. For example:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  @Input() selected: number = undefined;
  @Output() selectedChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
// ...
```

Then on hover, the change is emitted:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;
    // ...
    // some code to setting up the bar chart in d3
    // ...
    self.bars
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i){ 
            self.selectedChange.emit(i) 
    } );
}
```

And, the selected item is updated:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.bars
      .attr('class', ( d, i ) => {
        return i === this.selected ? 'bar selected' : 'bar';
      });
  }
```

But, I am not  sure if this is the right approach. If I had more than one property linked, or if the data had to be updated online, I am not sure how I could identify the attribute that has to be updated.

Here is a Plunker with a sample code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/XMRYRrAYMZHKKV9qy0i2?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by " if the data had to be updated online"? "If I had more than one property linked" you could pass an object like `{selected: 1, color: green}` instead of just `1`. Be aware that Angular change detection doesn't recognize changes within objects. Either you use observables to notify that the content changed or you pass a new instance of the class every time something changed.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious. In angularjs I could do something like:
    scope.$watch('selected', updateSelected);
    scope.$watch('selectedTime', updateSelectedTime);

So, I could run each update separately. Is there a way to do something like that in angular2? Or is this not the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: In Angular2 there is no scope. A shared service with one or more observables is ususlly the way to go. This way gained dramatic performance improvments.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at observables.

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html